# Validations problem in javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

My below is working to show of all the required fields but unable to submit the form once i get all the required information.

```
function validations()
{
    var t=0;
    j('.reqFields').each(function(){
    var fields1 = j(this).val();
    if(fields1 == '')
    {
        t=t+1;
        alert('eneter required fields');
        j(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
    else{ 

    return true;
    }
    });
}
```

VF page button is :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Process" action="{!Process}" onclick="if(!validations()) {return false;}"/>
```

Can u plz help..

Comment: You return true from the inner function (each()). But the outer function will always return null.

Comment: Thanks Lex. I have written true section outside of If block and it fixed my issue. I need another suggestion i.e. if all fields are not null then i should start validating the size/email/spl characters validations. My problems is i used same styleclass name for all the fields. now how can i re-validate them in terms of email,length etc....

Comment: If you use jQuery instead of JS, there's the jQuery Validate plug-in that includes numerous methods for email, field length, State, Country, etc. I don't know if there's an equivalent for JS, but you could always look at the code for the methods and create your own. http://jqueryvalidation.org/